# How to measure time of replicating mongo database?

Tags: mongodb

I perform a write operation with a huge data to primary server.
How to measure time since data available on primary server to secondary server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/troubleshoot-replica-sets/#check-the-replication-lag:

> To check the current length of replication lag:
>
> In a mongo shell connected to the primary, call the rs.printSlaveReplicationInfo() method.
>
> Returns the syncedTo value for each member, which shows the time when the last oplog entry was written to the secondary, as shown in the following example:
>
> ```
> source: m1.example.net:27017
>     syncedTo: Thu Apr 10 2014 10:27:47 GMT-0400 (EDT)
>     0 secs (0 hrs) behind the primary
> source: m2.example.net:27017
>     syncedTo: Thu Apr 10 2014 10:27:47 GMT-0400 (EDT)
>     0 secs (0 hrs) behind the primary
> ```